# how to reference a JSON object element by column

Tags: c#, json, object, serialization

I'm scraping some code together from samples on the web that takes a single row of data (returned row from SP) and uses JSON object serializer to send it back to the client aspx javascript page. To give you an idea of how the data is being built...

```
    public static string GetLogEntry(DataTable table, string id)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row;

       foreach (DataRow dr in table.Select("UID =" + id))
       // foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
       var json = jss.Serialize(rows);
       return json;
```

I understand I have an unnecessary loop here because this particular SP is only designed to return a single row. I'll be working on that in the next chapter. My real issue is I don't understand how to extract the data I need.

My client loop is returning the data but I'm having a hard time referencing specific column data individually.

```
success: function (json) {    //ajax call success function
   var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);    // this line isn't really doing anything right now
   eval("var datax = " + json); 
   for (var propertyName in $(datax)[0]) {
      alert('data: ' + propertyName ); }    //this returns only the column names


   $(data).each(function (key, val) {

   for (var propertyName in val) {
      alert('data: ' + val[propertyName]); }
```

So what I'm wanting to do is access an element by the column name like I've seen in other examples....

```
alert(json.columnName) //returns undefine.
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your ajax call is made, the variable `json` in your success handler is already a javascript object literal.

```
function successHandler(resp){
    var data = resp;

    $.each(data, function (index, row){
        var key;
        foreach (key in row){
            if (row.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                console.log(key, row[key]);
            }
        }
    });
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "some url",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json"
}).done(successHandler);
```

It would help a lot if you could post the data as returned by the server. That would give us an idea of the structure of `json`.

As such, there shouldn't be any need to use `eval` or to parse the server response.

Btw, there is no such thing as a [JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). JSON is simply a format to serialize and pass around javascript object literals. The following,

```
var data = new List<Dictionary<string, object>> 
           {
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "Col1", 1.0}, { "Col2", 2.0}
                },
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "Col1", 1.1}, { "Col2", 2.2}
                },
           };
```

will be converted to the following string as per the JSON format:

```
"[{\"Col1\":1,\"Col2\":2},{\"Col1\":1.1,\"Col2\":2.2}]"
```

jQuery ajax will automatically parse this string and pass the resultant array to the success handler. For this to happen, jquery needs to be told to expect `json` data and the server needs to send back a string with the mimetype `application/json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: Lots of effort put into this informative response. as @Amith stated, I didn't need to use the `eval`. After the line `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);` I was able to get the data I needed like this: `alert(obj[0].columnName)`. and `alert(json.columnName)` returned undefined. More detail: json data was being returned in the following format: `[{\"columnName\":variable,\"columnName\":variable  }]"`